# In frame animation - How to remove bitmap size exceeds VM budget error in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to do animation using more images. So I am using frame by frame animation. But I am facing `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`. I have searched the Internet, but I don't have any idea. Anyone please  help me.

I tried using the below code:

**activity.java**

```java
scr1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.data9);
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation9 = (AnimationDrawable)scr1.getBackground();
frameAnimation9.start();
frameAnimation9.setOneShot(true);
```

**data9.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/s1" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/s3" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/s5" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/s6" android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outof memory bitmap size exceeds VM budget this exception occurs when you are loading multiple number of images which are large in size at once. The VM size varies from devices to devices usually if you are using a high end device you may face this issue rarely. after pixel conversion of your total images, your total image size should not exceed 12MB to be on safer size.

so what you can do is you can reduce your image size by compressing them or else you can combine all the images to form a .gif and then use a videoview for the gif to play.(see to it that your gif is not too large) this may help.

Comment: thankyou for ur response. my all images now png format so  i need to convert my all images to .gif format?